# Don't review a first question by simply downvoting it or voting to close it

Tags: discussion, review, etiquette, new-users

A fair amount of first questions are of very low quality. Even so, I think that it is not correct, when a user gets one such first post from the First Questions review queue, to simply downvote it or to vote to close it. The person who posted it should get some comment explaining what is wrong (or, at least, a part of what is wrong) with that post. So, unless the act of voting to close the question will actually close it right away (in which case whoever posted the question will get a message) or if the question seems to have been posted by a troll, I think that one of our etiquette rules should be to leave some critique to the new user (assuming that the question is of low quality). Or to upvote some comment containing such a remark, if there is one.

Comment: If very low quality questions are not closed early, they get answered quickly, after which the asker has little motivation to improve the question.  Closing a very poor question isn't the end for the asker: it means *improve the post*.

Comment: @amWhy What has your second comment to do with my question? I wrote nothing against downvoting, only against doing just that.

Comment: On main https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222954/prevent-downvoting-in-the-first-post-review

Comment: @TheSimpliFire That's interesting. I did a search here before posting, but not on the Main Meta.

Comment: Most users are students here and they know the rules. Because these rules are the same in real life. Don't ask your teachers and others students for solutions to your homework because no one is going to do your homework in real life and this is the same rule that apply here. If you post a question without showing some efforts it's clear that it will be closed very soon.

Comment: Some users leave that kind of message already, and it's always more or less the same, on questions. It may be a good idea to post a comment automatically, as is done with some close votes (duplicates among others). Apart from that, even if the new user may feel badly about the site because of an early downvote or close vote, they often already know the rules, as Satyendra wrote above. It should be obvious for them that asking without trying is cheating.

Comment: It may be less obvious for answers. Regarding another comon case (new answer by a new user on an old question, often >1 year), given that they are either duplicate answers or plain BS in more than 90% of cases from my experience in review, I would simply block such answers until a certain reputation is attained.

Comment: @Satyendra There are several other potential problems with questions posted by new users, such as asking off-topic questions, or asking questions which are too broad.

Comment: And, as @Jean-ClaudeArbaut mentioned, there are also the users which are posting an *answer* for the first time.

Comment: I believe you are right. If read too quickly, your question leaves the impression that you mean *"Don't downvote and don't close"*, but we could do a bit more, at least in some cases - well *I* could, certainly, as I seldom add a message during a review.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I surely vote to close many first questions (and I sometimes downvote them). But I think that, at least when we are getting them on the First Posts queue, we should then *also* tell something to the poster (or to upvote a comment which criticizes the post).

Comment: By the way, I don't think *your* question deserves to be downvoted or closed. But I think it's an example of what [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) meant in his profile. If it can't be discussed here, where will it ever be?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do agree on that with you...

Comment: Somewhat related: [When closing question for lack of effort, leave a comment to OP explaining what to do](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9285). (However, the post is from 2013, when the site wasn't flooded by new low quality questions as much as it is toady.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for adding the [tag:new-users] tag to my question. I was unaware of its existence.

Comment: Here is my take. When I start reviewing I start from the red dot of close queue and by the time I deal with 20 posts there the first posts queue gets cleared. In case there is any chance of getting to first posts, already one has seen far worse questions from those 20 in close queue and there may be less of an incentive to give feedback via comment. However if one starts with the first posts queue I think reviewers will have more chance to give feedback via comments.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  You say "I don't think your question deserves to be downvoted or closed."  I agree that this discussion is more-or-less on-topic (though probably a duplicate), so perhaps not in need of closure.  On the other hand, votes on meta indicate agreement or disagreement.  When you suggest that the post shouldn't be downvoted, you are implicitly suggesting that no one should have any reason to disagree with the content of the post.  This may not be what you meant, but it is how it comes across.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was not aware of the interpretation *votes on meta indicate agreement or disagreement* (my bad, it's [well known](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18811/downvoting-on-meta-and-disappearance-from-the-front-page)). Thanks for the clarification. With this meaning, of course downvotes are acceptable.

Comment: Another potential problem are those tests that see if you pay attention, and sometimes flagging or downvoting is the correct answer. In that case, if you can't tell the difference between tests or if they are real new-comer questions, then it's safer to err on the side of caution and just downvote/flag.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I remember when I asked my first question on MSE. I couldn't even use math jax until my 10th post(I am not sure maybe until fifth post). luckily I didn't face many downvotes.

Comment: @philomath It is not lucky, it probably means you did the other things right, like posting attempts, being active with comments, and being receptive to feedback. In fact, looking back at some of your early questions, I think you were far better equipped than most first users.

Comment: of course!  I almost cried because for almost 3 days I was confused about trivial matters and when I asked this on the website I often got downvotes.  I only care about this website purely for knowledge seeking and without intend to troll posting.  But unfortunately they often underestimate questions that are easy for them but difficult for me.  That's so cruel! At least they should give a hint. A little hint is enough. People are so mean here. Sorry.

Comment: @user516076 I understand your point of view, please do not be sorry for your experience, because you have said what you felt and the site needs to hear it. I have seen your questions, and apart from one or two I do not think even the first ones you've posted lack quality. I hope your experience of the site has improved.  Having said that, please remember that many people who also faced the same problem as you just left the site, and you were one of the few who continued to persist. Eventually, the good contributor in you came out from posting quality questions. You deserve credit for that.

Comment: @user516076 You have been through bad experiences, and some others probably have been through it too : the past is in the past, now we must strive to ensure that nobody new to the site who is genuinely interested and who posts good quality questions gets ignored on the site, regardless of the difficulty level of their question.  There's not many better than you to do that, as a person who has been through the rough and tumble of a newbie on the site asking elementary questions.

Comment: Downvotes and close votes are *supposed* to be anonymous. Asking people to state why they are taking these actions undermines that anonymity. I cannot agree with this. New users can seek advice through meta or chats. If they are somehow unwilling, this site has a door that won’t hit them on the way out. We don’t have time to leave comments when the site is being nonstop flooded by bad question “spam”.

Comment: @user64742 Your point deserves more discussion, in my opinion it qualifies as an answer to this question, and is different from the others because it disagrees with José.  I appreciate your unique line of thinking, and I can see where  you are coming from : revealing your identity means that you could be subject to serial downvoting and trolling (there may be better reasons, this is my best reason). One way to overcome this is to have the option of an "anonymous" message i.e. a comment whose poster is not revealed. This has downsides as well, but that I can discuss if you write an answer.

Comment: How are you sure that users do this from the review queue and not just by clicking on the question from the front site?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I am *not* sure. I am just suggesting an etiquette rule.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Just wanted to bring to your attention again the comment by user64742 above. I would like to know what you think, because his concern of anonymity being compromised by commenting, is different from what the others have said. He is right in some sense : if you are keeping downvotes anonymous for a reason, the same applies to not leaving a comment there, independent of whoever's post it is. I would like to know what you think about this. It could of course be that you just don't agree : and I would understand that too.

Comment: @user64742 There is some confusion here. In the first place, my suggestion has *nothing* to do with downvoting; it's only about voting to close a question. In the second place, voting to close is *not* anonymous; if the question gets closed, then the names of those who voted to close it is visible, at least to the author of the question and to those users with high enough reputation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I missed that comment. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are welcome. I just felt it was not a run-of-the-mill comment.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have recently also seen a comment that is kind of standard from you for new users. I like that comment. Could you please share it here so I can use it to welcome new users too? Also what you had said is very relevant and I agree. Especially [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495350/equation-of-hyperbola-to-look-like-the-figure) lead me to think about it. I think one more thing is for MSE members to edit new users' questions or provide them a few examples so they may understand the point. Is there a post with examples of good (newbie) questions?

Comment: @InanimateBeing Many of my comments are taken from [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates). Is it one of them? And I am not aware of a post with examples of good (newbie) questions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is not from that post, it was a bit different and started with "Welcome to MSE! ..." I noticed you use the same one 2-3 times. Maybe they were the only times.

Comment: @InanimateBeing Most of my comments to new users begin with those words. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to be more specific but sadly I can't remember anything beyond those words. Well, thanks anyways, when I come across it I'll let you know which one I was talking about. I asked because I thought you use the same one always as like a standard. That's not the case though. The comment was quite big though, but so is the one in the link you gave, so again not helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Above was the comment (to best of my recalling) that I was talking about and yes you were right, it is indeed from the same link just wasn't sure then

Answer (score 39):

*Originally intended to be a comment, but I find that it is more of an answer than a comment.*

I would suggest modifying the website to force newcomers to read the "Asking a good question" (and possibly making it a bit more detailed than it is now) and a **small quiz** to verify that they have read the rules. This method will reduce the number of new questions that violate the rules, and thus solve this problem.

Thanks to @Ennar in the comments,

> You could simply show examples of good and bad questions and explain the difference.

Comment: This entry barrier will run counter to the company's goal of increasing user base and thus less likely to be implemented.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh The company's goal of increasing user base will continue to happen regardless: math.se clearly monopolises the "online math questions and answers" website market. Furthermore, you can see in Joe's answer that the advice on how to write a good question it rather short. I think I actually agree with this answer, so long as the quiz is short and doesn't come across as patronising.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: I also agree with the answer, but I doubt if SE overlords will also agree.

Comment: You could simply show examples of good and bad questions and explain the difference. I think it will get the point across faster than just writing down the "rules" as if a question was an essay.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Not just that. They monopolize the online mathematical community. There is no other site one can go to discuss mathematics. This therefore means ***all*** users interested in math will join this site.

Comment: Downvoted enthusiastically.

Comment: @DavidDiaz What do you disagree with?

Comment: Your answer does not address the post (preventing harm to new users, and implicitly the community, by effortless question gatekeeping). Suggestions/ideas for changing the quality of questions that reach the first post review queue is a red herring topic. There is prior evidence that you conflate these issues: In your comment to the post you assert that in coin flip situations, close voting is the cautious choice. This is capital eff false. Your ability to gatekeep is not more important than feedback offered to the new user and others through public communication.

Comment: @DavidDiaz Right, but if they were to thoroughly read the "Asking a good question," and seeing good examples, then they will start asking better questions, and already learn what good question looks like, so that decreases the chances that we would need to downvote or close. *An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.* That's my solution to this issue. If you have a better suggestion then you can add your own answer.

Comment: no, no, no. If you have an answer *for an entirely different question*, you should post a new question.

Comment: @DavidDiaz Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? I think my answer should successfully solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Why do you think that the quality of feedback offered to users [the topic at hand], is addressed by improving the quality of question reaching the first post queue [your topic]?

Comment: @DavidDiaz The title said "Don't review a first post by simply downvoting it or voting to close it." While I agree that how to improve the quality of feedback is the question, if we decrease the number of low-quality posts, then the quality of questions will improve, and therefore will be no need for closing or downvoting (ideally), and so therefore constructive feedback will be provided. We are not going to provide "constructive feedback" for homework questions that asks you to solve the problem without trying anything or question that just go 'asdfkljasdfv," right? They are sadly too common.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119074/discussion-between-kinglogic-and-david-diaz).

Comment: There are a long chain of shaky assumptions that must be true for your answer to completely address the question. Don't let the upvotes get to you: you can do better.  You can start by valuing other people's time, effort, and intentions in a way that allows you to find value in doing more than mouse clicking. If this is impossible, have you considered not reviewing first posts?

Comment: There is a recent question with a similar suggestion: [Proposal: Require first time question askers to pass a short quiz on how to ask a good question, before posting their first question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35289).

Comment: At the end of the post you've mentioned examples of good questions - some related posts here on meta: 
[Suggestions for examples of well-asked questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20893), 
[Standard example of well asked question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20792) and 
[Examples and counterexamples of good questions and answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8190).

Answer (score 13):

I agree that the First Posts review queue calls upon Reviewers to do more than simply downvote and close.  The instructions at the top of that page say:

> This is the first question asked by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post.

An anonymous downvote or vote-to-close **without feedback** is particularly unlikely to "help them learn" when new users post for the first time.  I note the Comment by Satyendra:

> Most users are students here and they know the rules.

The first part of this is unobjectionable.  I consider myself a student-for-life, and the purpose of the site is to help learn mathematics.  But the second part deserves critical analysis.

In addition to the mechanical rules of how the SE software works and is intended to be used, the Math.SE Community has crafted a tradition of what Questions are allowed to be asked (the traditions vary across SE Communities in substantial ways).

If one voluntarily goes into the First Post review queue, I believe one assumes responsibility for providing constructive feedback about the posts found there.

Comment: But the responsibility of using correctly a site does not lie solely on moderation. The user has to "do his homework" about this too. Maybe it could help to make the... help more accessible, especially when asking or posting for the first time? Anyway, when I arrive in a new user community, my first obligation is to learn its rules. I can only blame myself if I don't and I get frowned upon. And in this regard, Math.SE is absolutely not the worst I have seen. Even on the SE network, it's more friendly than SO, for instance - it's my impression.

Comment: Exactly and furthermore, MSE is not an exo planet with strange and unknown rules. The rules we have here are the same ones we have  in real life. To get some help with homework you need to show your efforts thats how ir works in college and high schools. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: And everyone is pretending that every "first time user is new to this site."  Hah!  If you believe that, I'd like to sell you a plot of land on the moon.  I can't tell you how many times one question is closed, only to see, five minutes later, the very same question, verbatim, typos and all, reposted from yet another "new user."  If careless homework-answer-seekers abuse this site, I'm not going to waste my time spoon feeding them with yet another tutorial on how this site works.  To many users are coming here each day to create yet another "disposable" account.

Comment: hardmath  Do you also believe that when upvoting a new user, it is crucial that you explain to the user why you upvoted?  After all, upvoting with no justification can leave a student just as confused: why did I get this upvote, when another question I asked didn't?  What was better about this question than the other one I asked?  Without explanation, as you're arguing, a vote, whether up or down, can be confusing.  So, are you onboard in arguing that all votes, up and down, especially for new users, should be accompanied by a comment from the voter?  If not, I think you haven't a point.

Comment: @amWhy Any feedback must be meaningful. An upvote means what it means: good question, and since the guy did it right, he has probably read and understands the rules. A downvote says it's not a good question, but it doesn't say why. It's like a grade: you won't explain a student why he got an A, but if he got an F and you want him to make progress, you better tell him what he did wrong. But in some cases, a question - or an answer - may deserve a positive comment. I do that, sometimes.

Comment: An upvote doesn't say why the post was good, nor the reason for the upvote, anymore than a downvote expresses why the post is bad.  You can't have it both ways, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut